# How to compare two MyDouble values?

Tags: java, polynomial-math

I want to compare two `MyDouble` values with zero.

```
if(getA()>(MyDouble.zero)) //where getA() is MyDouble
```

But it does not let me do that. Does anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: its a custom class like Double but carries a Double Value.

Comment: What does your custom class add to the behavior that would be worth the effort?

Answer (score 2):

You have to write a `Comparator<MyDouble>` that does the job.  You'll implement the [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

You won't be able to use the '>' comparison symbols to do it.  You'll do something like this:

```
x.compareTo(y)
```

Comment: To clarify why you cannot do '>' comparison here... Java does not have operator overloading. Only native numeric primitives can be used with operators. For custom objects, you use functions.

Comment: if (!getB().equals(MyDouble.zero)) {
          
             if (getB().compareTo(MyDouble.zero)) {
              
                 return getB();

Answer (score 0):

You should implement duffmo's solution as this is what Double and all Numbers do.  Another way to solve this is to access the fields directly or provide a specific method to do the comparison. (This could be more efficient than implementing compareTo)

```
if(getA().value > MyDouble.ZERO.value) // Constants are in UPPER_CASE
```

or

```
if(getA().greaterThan(MyDouble.ZERO))
```

Comment: if(!getB().equals(MyDouble.zero)){
         if (getB().compareTo(DEFAULT_B))
        poly += getB().toString() + "x";

Comment: @javaLearner, compareTo returns an `int` not a boolean. Not sure why you would do equals and compareTo as this is redundant.  You don't need to call `toString()` as it will do this anyway.